# File uploads with typegraphql (Apollo Server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apollo-server, typegraphql

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to get file uploads working with `typegraphql` (wrapper on Apollo Server). I am writing a simple resolver that should receive a file upload and write it to a file on the server.

### My code

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s35EmAn9Zl8)

I have uploaded a very small demo of the problem to this [github repo](https://github.com/ziggy6792/graphql-file-uploads).
And here is my resolver for receiving the uploaded file

```
@Resolver()
export class ProfilePictureResolver {
  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async addProfilePicture(
    @Arg('picture', () => GraphQLUpload)
    upload: FileUpload
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('upload', upload);
    const { createReadStream, filename } = upload;
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
      createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(__dirname + `/../../../images/${filename}`))
        .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
        .on('close', () => resolve(true))
        .on('error', () => reject(false))
    );
  }
}
```

### My Problem

When I run this resolver (using postman as shown in the tutorial) the promise never resolves. `createReadStream` doesn't emit a close or error or finish event. The image file does get created but it is empty (0 bytes).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I make this in a different way maybe this can help you I use `graphql-upload` library to upload an image

in your index or server file, you need to have this, in my case I do it whit express, but there is a setup whit apollo

```
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from 'graphql-upload'
import { graphqlHTTP }  from 'express-graphql';

    App.use('/graphql', graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 }), graphqlHTTP(async(req, res) => 
    ({
        schema: await buildSchema
        ({
            resolvers: 
            [
                ProfilePictureResolver ,
            ],

        }),


    })));
```

And the resolver

```
@Resolver()
export class ProfilePictureResolver 
{
  @Mutation(() => Boolean)
  async addProfilePicture(
  @Arg('picture', () => GraphQLUpload)upload: FileUpload): Promise<boolean> 
  {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>
      createReadStream()
        .pipe(createWriteStream(__dirname + `/../../../images/${filename}`))
        .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
        .on('close', () => resolve(true))
        .on('error', () => reject(false))
    );
  }
}
```

the createReadStream make a file in your folder I think it is better to upload to your storage server directly but continue whit this, postman Is a little bit harder to use whit graphql you can try to use [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/)

Her you can see the option to [Upload the file whit altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/docs/features/file-upload.html)

your Graphql query should look like this

```
mutation ($Picture: Upload!)
{
  
  addProfilePicture
  (
    upload: $Picture,
  )
}
```